# Download Video using node js

Tags: node.js, endpoint

I have one link, It's local, so this link if I write the link directly in chrome a video is downloaded.

this is the link `https://127.0.0.1:7001/api/media/getDirectDownloadVideo?username=admin&password=admin*&setCookie=true&camera_id={c22128b3-6af0-79b8-764e-62234dd023fc}&pos=2023-01-23T13:30&duration=10`

so I just want to implementate one function to get it, through node js, I'm using fetch, I create this function:

```
exports.getVideo = async (req, res) => {

    const path = process.env.APP_LOCALHOST_URL + urlDirectDownloadVideo(req.query);

    const response = await fetch(path,{
        method: 'GET', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.query.token}`
        },
    });
    return await response.json();
}
```

currently don't download the video, what I have to do? to downloaded it

Comment: you are re-declaring `res` variable and return `response.json()` instead of `res.json()`?

Comment: not really, let me update it.